# What is the proper way to use check boxes to set flags in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have an model containing a flags column. Inside the column is a number representing the flag state. All flags enabled is represented by 0b1111111, and individual options look something like 0b0010000 or 0b0000001. I want to have a form with check boxes (in this case 7 check boxes), and I want params[:flags] to be set to bitwise or of the selected boxes. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading up on [bitwise numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) as what you are storing isnt bitwise, you are simple flipping 7 0's and 1's in sequential order.

if you are looking to use bitwise you store an integer, with 7 checkbox your column will need to support a number of up to 256.

the check_box_tag has a 'checked' attribute, which you would simple pass the bitwise operator to which returns a boolean

```
check_box_tag("name", value, (persisted_value | value of this checkbox))
```